# Prestashop - Unable to add the product (parsererror) when product has attributes

Tags: jquery, ajax, prestashop

I have a website using Prestashop 1.4.7.3 (and cannot upgrade it for now) and have trouble since 2 days when I try to add a product in ajax cart, this is the error message :

> TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to add the product.
>   Details:
>   Error thrown: [object XMLHttpRequest]
>   Text status: parsererror

I search the web since those 2 days and try everything i found (modifying content_dir, replacing mb_split by split, etc.) but nothing worked and now i don't know what to do and really need help.

With Firefox and Chrome, I have no error on console tab, and only have this alert when i add a product with attributes or if there's already a product with attributes in the cart.
When i click on "add", the cart is not refreshing and i have this alert, but if i refresh the page (with F5 or CTRL+R), i see the product correctly added.

Can someone help me please ? Or give me a clue ?

Thanks,

Tony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !

The problem came from the cart tpl file in the theme folder (in modules/blockcart).

The tpl has a replacement method for ' that replace / too. As the attributes was created with / in the name, that was a real mess.

I commented the line using this method until i find how to replace it by a good one.

Hope it will help people in the same case.

Thx again gskema for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The returned JSON data has a PHP error message, which breaks JSON syntax -> cannot bet parsed.

What you can try doing:

1) Turning off `dev` mode in `defines.inc.php` - tis will turn off printing out PHP error message, hopefully fixing your JSON

2) Check you PHP error log. All PHP error message are also printed to logs. If you find the error, you will have to fix it.

3) Track down JS code, where it tries to parse received JSON data - probably `ajax-cart.js`. Somewhere is this file the code is trying to parse received data, you need to add `console.log(data)` and you will be able to see what broke the JSON data.

Comment: Thx gskema, dev mode is already set as false in defines.inc.php, i have no error in the centos httpd error.log, so i guess i have to follow the JS console.log. I hope i'll find something...

Answer (score 0):

can you explain what did you do to solve it?

The tpl has a replacement method for ' that replace / too. As the attributes was created with / in the name, that was a real mess.

I am on my blockcart.tpl but I can't see any method that replace /.

Comment: Hi phingko,

Your problem may be different from mine : My problem came from a mistake created by the theme developer, so it's quite specific.

My guess is you should create another question explaining your problem, i'll be glad to help.